# Task Scheduler? Command-line? Need "Export URLs" to csv file daily.

Tags: google-search-appliance

Is there a way to export daily all indexed URLs to a CSV or ZIP file?

So, a daily scheduled task of:

Index => Diagnostics => Export URLs => Generate the gzip file => Download

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for this.  You would need to use some sort of screen capture/macro recording software to do this, from what I've seen.

Comment: Thanks Terry! This is a bit of a surprise given the product, so it means there is still room in the Search business after all. I'll export manually every day for now.

Comment: Since the GSA was deprecated 2 years ago, there's been no active feature development.